# How could I program live timer countdown?

Tags: angularjs, countdowntimer

I have done an AngularJS timer countdown but when page reloads the count down start over. My objective is to have a countdown that counts down after page is reloaded.
Thanks!

Here you have my code ->

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="timerApp" ng-controller="TimeControll">
    <timer autostart="false" interval="1000" countdown="345600">{{ days }} days, {{ hours }} hours, {{ minutes }} minutes, {{ seconds }} seconds.</timer>
    <button ng-click="startTimer()" ng-disabled="timerRunning">Start Timer</button>
    <button ng-click="stopTimer()" ng-disabled="!timerRunning">Stop Timer</button>
</div>
```

Angular JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var eventApp = angular.module('timerApp', ['timer'], function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
    });
    function TimeControll($scope, $http) {
        $scope.timerRunning = false;

        $scope.startTimer = function (){
            $scope.$broadcast('timer-start');
            $scope.timerRunning = true;
        };

        $scope.stopTimer = function (){
            $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
            $scope.timerRunning = false;

        };

        $scope.$on('timer-stopped', function (event, data){
            console.log('Timer Stopped - data = ', data);
        });

    }
    TimeControll.$inject = ['$scope'];
</script>
```

Comment: use localstorage for saving your data

Comment: Javascript will forget everything once the page is reloaded (unless you are developing a SPA) . You have to use client 's local storage to maintain the state of the time, which can be cookies or html5's local storage. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp